# On Demand downloading levels in HTML5 Mobile Application

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, meteor

So after spending some time with Meteor, I found that this is probably the best isomorphic data-centric framework to build web applications.

I am currently trying to build an HTML5 mobile application for Kids (Under 5 Years), the content of the application should get updated as the child progresses solving and interacting with the available activities. (So new activities should be downloaded at runtime of the application).

Mobile support of Meteor is good. Meteor + Cordova can serve my purpose.

But what I am confused about is:

Is Meteor is the best framework for my use case, where the application is mostly static. No state to be maintained across. (Only the number of levels crossed by the user has to be synced.)
But Application need something like Hot Code Push, (Don't know how to maintain that differently for each account)

If not, then what is the preferred tech-stack to build HTML5 mobile applications/games where it is required to push levels or new activities at runtime and that too differently for different users/clients. (Some might be the premium subscribed users getting extra level/activities on monthly basis.)